# require all files dynamically with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, browserify

i have this giant file where i'm requiring all files in directories:

```
require('./adminAppConfig');
require('./breadcrumb/BreadcrumbController');
require('./calendar/CalendarController');
require('./calendar/calendarDirective');
require('./chart/ChartController');
require('./dashboard/DashBoardController');
require('./email/EmailController');
require('./error/ErrorController');
require('./event/EventController');
require('./navbar/NavbarController');
require('./navbar/navbarDirective');
require('./service/ServiceController');
require('./sidebar/SidebarController');
require('./warning/WarningController');
require('./common/directives/chartDirective');
require('./common/directives/controllerActionDirective');
require('./common/directives/controllerDirective');
require('./common/directives/emailDirective');
require('./common/directives/dataSidebarDirective');
require('./common/directives/serviceDirective');
require('./common/directives/tableDirective');
require('./common/models/BookingModel');
require('./common/models/EventModel');
require('./common/services/layoutService');
require('./common/services/watchService');
```

I want know if is possible require all without write one by one.

I was trying to:

```
require('./*.js');
require('./*/*.js');
require('./*/*/*.js');
```

But that doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: either https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-glob-loader or https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-require might be helpful, but i'm not sure how well either will work with browserify.

Comment: but, to answer your question, no, that isn't possible, without additional modules.